# Can not build JHipster project after installation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, jhipster

I use JHipster to generate microservice project (uaa).
After installation I can't build project.

I try to change java versions:

> jdk1.8.0_211
>
> jdk-10.0.2
>
> java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64

My Maven version

> => mvn -version
>
> Apache Maven 3.6.0

Used different JHipster versions:

> 6.0.1
>
> 6.0.0
>
> 5.8.2

Nodejs (I use LTS, but before used to 12)

> => node -v v10.15.2

Npm

> => npm -v
>
> 5.8.0

My OS

> Debian.

```
=> ./mvnw 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.mycompany.myapp:uaa >-----------------------
[INFO] Building Uaa 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ uaa >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:copy-resources (default-resources) @ uaa ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ uaa ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ uaa ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.3:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ uaa ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/coder/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.3/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.3-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/coder/Desktop/jhipapp/uaa/target/jacoco/test.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ uaa ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ uaa ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 66 source files to /home/coder/Desktop/jhipapp/uaa/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ uaa ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ uaa ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 19 source files to /home/coder/Desktop/jhipapp/uaa/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ uaa <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ uaa ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/coder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/coder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/coder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/coder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/home/coder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/home/coder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/home/coder/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar

        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????   ??????? ????????? ????????? ????????
        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????? ???????? ????????? ????????? ?????????    
        ??? ?????????    ???    ????????? ???????     ???    ???????   ?????????    
  ???   ??? ?????????    ???    ????????   ???????    ???    ???????   ????????     
  ????????? ???   ??? ????????? ???       ????????    ???    ????????? ???  ????    
   ???????  ???   ??? ????????? ???       ???????     ???    ????????? ???   ???    

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::                                                     

2019-05-12 00:48:57.049  WARN 29889 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Unable to load consul config from config/uaa-swagger/

com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8500 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:77)
        at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.makeGetRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:34)
        at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:128)
        at com.ecwid.consul.v1.kv.KeyValueConsulClient.getKVValues(KeyValueConsulClient.java:150)
        at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.getKVValues(ConsulClient.java:534)
        at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySource.init(ConsulPropertySource.java:67)
        at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.create(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:179)
        at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:139)
        at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b35ebf8.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
        at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e381a286.locate(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:649)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at com.mycompany.myapp.UaaApp.main(UaaApp.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8500 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:221)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:140)
        at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:61)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
2019-05-12 00:48:57.125  INFO 29889 --- [  restartedMain] com.mycompany.myapp.UaaApp               : The following profiles are active: dev,swagger
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose to enable Consul for the Service Discovery option, so you must start it before starting your apps.

A docker-compose file is supplied in `src/main/docker/consul.yml`, which you can launch with `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/consul.yml up -d`

Comment: There is still a mistake. Now it can't find `JAXBException`. I added packages jaxb-core and jaxb-api but that didn't help me.

Comment: That's a separate issue.  Did you try following https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/3737815 ?

Comment: Thank you @Jon Ruddel. Your answer was correct, but I can't vote because my rating is too small.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."